# Difference between using a pointer and a class for creating a modeless window in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

This [resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC) describes a method of creating a modeless dialog using pointers. They create a pointer that pointer to the dialog class and then use the -> syntax.

```
CModeLess *m_pmodeless = new CModeLess(this);
m_pmodeless->Create(CModeLess::IDD);
m_pmodeless->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

I have been doing something like this so far:

```
CModeLess m_pmodeless;
m_pmodeless.Create(IDD_DIALOG);
m_pmodeless.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

I do this mainly because I feel comfortable using classes. Is there any disadvantage of using this approach?

Secondly, in the pointer approach I have to do something like this to close the window: (if I am not mistaken)

```
if(m_pmodeless != NULL) { delete m_pmodeless; }
```

Is there some deletion I have to do If I use classes or is `m_pmodeless.closeWindow()` enough?

I apologize if this is a very basic question, but i'm curious to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question to answer, as a lot depends on exactly what you are trying to do and also on exactly how CModeless is implemented. In general you are right to avoid pointers, but GUI programming has special issues because the C++ objects in your program represent GUI objects on the screen, and coordinating the destruction of the C++ objects in your program with the GUI objects on the screen can be quite tricky. Sometimes pointers are the simplest answer to this problem.

I'm assuming that m_pmodeless is a member variable of another class.

One issue is the lifetime of the objects. In the class version the CModeless object will be destroyed when the containing object is destroyed. Whether that's OK for you depends on your code. Whether that also destroys the modeless dialog depends on how CModeless is implemented. You need to look at the CModeless destructor if you can, or the documentation for CModeless if you can't. With the pointer version you have explicit control over when the object is destroyed, just call delete at the right time.

Another issue is that some GUI libraries automatically delete the C++ object when the GUI object is destroyed. Something like this (on Windows)

```
case WM_NCDESTROY:
   ...
   // last message received so delete the object
   delete this;
   break;
```

Code like this is assuming that all your objects are heap allocated and automatically deleting them for you at the right time. If CModeless is written like this then you have no choice but to use the pointer version.

Comment: I see by checking the link you posted that CModeless does do `delete this;`. So you have no choice, you must use the pointer version. It also mean that you should not delete yourself, CModeless is doing it for you. Just destroy the window and the delete will happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. A class based approach would then be suited for a simpler dialog box like a progress window or a pseudo-modal dialog where some temporary output related to a process is displayed? (Basically where we know that the dialog must be closed/ have control over its life-span and no memory is initialized by it)

Comment: @eternalDreamer Exactly, if the GUI object has a simple lifespan like a modal dialog, then not using a pointer should be fine. Another example would be a child window that always gets destroyed when it's parent window is destroyed. In that case a non-pointer class member variable makes sense. But all of this is overridden by `delete this;` in this case always use new and a pointer.